# How to create a expanding CSS Grid with a fixed element inside?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a css grid that expands in height as the content inside adjusts, whilst also anchoring an element to the bottom of the grid item without any content overlap.

I'd like all of the items to adjust evenly based on the lowest grid item, so if item A is deeper, item B and C should match A with the anchored element also aligning with lowest anchored element from the row. At the moment the content above is overlapping the bottom element and I can't land on the solution.

I currently have the below code (also here https://jsfiddle.net/pajov3rb/4/)

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Thanks for your help in advance!
Neal

```css
.homes-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(300px, auto);
}

.home-tile-div {
  position: relative;
}

.home-title,
.home-location,
.home-telephone,
.home-email-address {
  font-size: 1.6rem !important;
}

.home-more-info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="homes-wrapper">
  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post Code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post Code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, then you are talking about overlapping of the content with **Find Out More** button.Use `@media` queries and **top** for spacing:

```css
.homes-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(300px, auto);
}

.home-tile-div {
  position: relative;
}

.home-title,
.home-location,
.home-telephone,
.home-email-address {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.home-more-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    background-color: #22acc6;
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

body{
  overflow-y:auto;
  
}

@media all and (max-width:1060px){
.homes-wrapper {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 80px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(320px, auto);
  
}
.home-more-info {
  top:100%;
  width:70%;
  
}
}
```

```html
<article class="homes-wrapper">
  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number Telephone Number Telephone Number Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post Code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us or email us or email us or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post Code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>

  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number Telephone Number Telephone Number Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post Code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us or email us or email us or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-tile-div">
    <div class="home-title">Title Goes Here</div>
    <div class="home-location">Location<br>Post Code</div>
    <div class="home-telephone">Telephone Number</div>
    <div class="home-email-address">or email us</div>
    <div class="home-more-info">Find out more</div>
  </div>
  </article>
```

Comment: Thank you @rishab that works well as long as the content in each grid item is the same. 

If one item has more content than the others e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/pajov3rb/5/ it means that the "find out more" button is misaligned between the items. Ideally I would like the "find out more" to be aligned evenly across the bottom of the grid items based on the deepest item. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I have worked on that for you.Here is the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/cp82grsb/1/

Comment: Thanks! The problem you get when the "find out more" button is set to absolute like that is it floats on top of any other content below that row. So i've introduced another row below, which is how it will be displayed in the final build, and as you can see it introduces overlap https://jsfiddle.net/joeLhcqw/1/

Comment: Yes that seems to be it. Thanks! If I wanted the same row to wrap at a certain browser size e.g. change from a row of 3 to a row of 2 at 1060px would that be a case of playing with the margin-top that you've added at that resolution to avoid any overlapping? e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/ayb6csg2/

Comment: I have changed the html structure a little bit and replaced the top level `<div>` with `<article>` to make things working https://jsfiddle.net/zdaejc2m/3/

Comment: Ah yes that looks like it's nearly there and thanks for tidying up the code. The only issue is that we're still getting overlapping content behind the "find out more" button when reducing the browser size right down?

Comment: Now all problems are fixed https://jsfiddle.net/ks6ap02o/

Comment: **Perfect** that's fixed it all thank you. Did you want to add the update to your previous answer so I can confirm it's correct? If not I'll add it as a fresh one just the close the question off. Thanks so much for your help.